# lync integration in a web application or a sharepoint application

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, lync

My aim is to have personal status info(a string you wrote where "What is happening today?" box) on Microsoft's Lync in a web application.

I have used a code like this :

```
LyncClient lyncClient = LyncClient.GetClient();
var usrStatus = lyncClient.Self.Contact.GetContactInformation(ContactInformationType.PersonalNote);
```

but it doesn't worked.error was "the host process is not running".How can I get informations   from a lync profile ? Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the Lync client is running on the user's desktop in that [workstation context](http://bit.ly/RIIkRE).  Your ASP.NET app is running in a separate workstation context under the IIS process and does not have access to the Lync client running in the user context.

There is a way to do this and it involves using a web service, I'll see if I can dig up that link.